# Limit access to a single host

Tags: ubuntu, access-control, lan

I have two 2 hosts (A and B), each with a single network interface, directly connected to a 3G router, via the LAN ports. I've configured both host A and B gateway to point to the 3G router. However, host A is ONLY supposed to be connected to host B. How do I limit host A access to the exterior (i.e., the Internet)?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is remove the default route on host A. That way, it will only be able to contact other hosts on the local LAN, like host B. If you put up a host C on another LAN port, though, host A will be able to talk to it. The next step would be to put host A on a separate network/VLAN, and implement firewall rules to restrict it, though this would probably be overkill for a simple use case.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I owe you an apology. I did some additional testing and the rules as written below do not work as I expected. I've updated my answer to reflect the results of my testing.

You have a few options.

1. If the 3G router has firewall capabilities configure a firewall rule that drops all traffic to/from Host A.
2. Enable and configure ufw to only allow LAN traffic.
   [UFW Community Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW)

Something like

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw allow in from 192.168.0.0/24
sudo ufw allow out to 192.168.0.0/24
sudo ufw default deny outgoing
sudo ufw default deny incoming
```

This will create an explicit rule to allow traffic to/from your LAN and deny all other traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the default gateway from network settings

```
/etc/networking/interfaces
```

and restart the network

```
services networking restart
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

or

```
 route -n 
 route del default gw xxx.xxx.xx.gw
```

where xxx.xxx.xxx.gw is your gateway